# How many temporary extents is my oracle 10g session using?

Tags: oracle, temp-tables

I am trying to find out just how much temporary space each session connecting to my database is using, but I've not been able to figure it out. I am trying to determine if the number of extents in use by a particular session are overly high.

I tried looking at V$TEMP_EXTENT_POOL and V$TEMP_EXTENT_MAP, but cannot seem to find anything which will map it to a specific session.

Any thoughts on where to look would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM v$tempseg_usage
```

Note that `TEMPORARY` segments are used by queries, not sessions, and are freed after the query is complete.

Comment: GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLES can use temporary segments and may not be freed until the session ends or commits, depending on the table settings.